# How to minimize a function with 112 variables?

Tags: matlab, mathematical-optimization

I have a [non-negative function named `aim`](http://yun.baidu.com/share/link?shareid=1526393049&uk=3658535152) with 112 variables to minimize, but even

```
 fminsearch('aim',random('Normal',0,3,1,112),optimset('MaxFunEvals',100^141))
```

output that

```
 Exiting: Maximum number of iterations has been exceeded
       - increase MaxIter option.
       Current function value: 1.977209
```

As I know, the minimum of `aim` should be 0. But I just do not know what to do then.

---

### Edit

As suggested by Daniel, I increase `MaxIter`, and it output no warnings

```
 fminsearch('aim',random('Normal',0,3,1,112),optimset('MaxFunEvals',10^9,'MaxIter',10^9))
```

But `aim(ans)` output  0.4559 rather than 0.

This function may be not convex, so I use `random` for the starting points. And the function does not have discontinuities and the output is always real.

Comment: Did you try increasing MaxIter?

Comment: Same way you set the parameter `'MaxFunEvals'`. Type in `doc optimset` for more details. `optimset('MaxFunEvals',100^141,'MaxIter',...)`

Comment: @Daniel Hi, the result is not good, please see the update of the post.

Comment: First, check that your function does not have discontinuities and the output is always real. Second, it seems that your function is not convex, and it gets stacked in a local minima. So, try with different starting points.

Comment: Otherwise, try more robust optimization techniques, like BFGS http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/31237-broydon-fletcher-goldfarb-shanno-bfgs-method/content/BFGS%20method/BFGS.m

Comment: @tashuhka Yeah, so I use `random` for the starting points. And the function does not have discontinuities and the output is always real.

Answer (score 0):

If your function is not convex, you can try with different starting points, like:

```
% Parameters
Niter = 1e10;
Nparam = 112;

% Default
x_min = zeros(1,Nparam);
f_min = Inf;

% Find minima
for ii=1:Niter
  [x,f] = fminsearch('aim',random('Normal',0,3,1,Nparam),optimset('MaxFunEvals',100^141));
  if (f<f_min), 
    f_min = f;
    x_min = x;
 end
```

Comment: Each `fminsearch` may take more than half a minute, the whole program may run 10000 years.

Comment: Welcome to the Optimization world!!!  You can try to use other minimization technique (BFGS family is highly recommended), or you can apply dimensionality reduction before optimization (PCA, LDA, etc)

Comment: Thanks! I have try [Quai-Newton](https://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/tutorial/UnconstrainedOptimizationQuasiNewtonMethods.html), which is same as BFGS in Mathematica. But it is not good.